# Webpacked Angular app can't load external module defined inside an IIFE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, webpack, iife

I'm working with a legacy Angular codebase (v1.2), trying to implement Webpack as a frontend build system, and I've run into an odd problem with an external dependency. For various reasons, I can't touch the dependency or load it with Webpack. It's already loaded on the page in a script tag when my bundle loads, and I can't change that either. The problem is related to this approach to module definition:

```
(function(){

  var appServices = angular.module('appServices', []);

  appServices.factory('fooService', function(){...});

});
```

When I try to use this service inside my Webpacked modules via:

```
var app = angular.module('ApplicationModule', ['appServices']);
```

I get an error that reads:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: appServicesProvider <- appServices <- ApplicationModule
```

I believe the issue is a scoping problem related to the use of the IIFE and the `var` declaration, but I'm not sure what exactly is going on, or how to make the module accessible in my Webpacked code. I would assume that the issue lies with local scoping of the module declared within the IIFE, but appServices works fine in the rest of the legacy Angular code, which uses the same syntax as my Webpacked module, but loads via script tags instead. Any insight into what exactly is going on here, and how I might successfully load this dependency would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your webpack build using the same angular instance as external script tags do, or it includes its own version in the bundle?

Comment: It's using the same instance. Also, there are a few other dependencies from the same source that aren't wrapped in an IIFE that do load correctly in my Webpacked module.